# Для чего служит опция -b команды checkout?

Tags: git, git-checkout

В чем разница между командами `git checkout devel` и `git checkout –b devel`?

Comment: Первая переход в ветку, вторая создать и перейти в ветку `devel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создать ветку и сразу же перейти на неё, вы можете выполнить команду `git checkout` с ключом `-b`:

```
$ git checkout -b dev
```

Это сокращение для:

```
$ git branch dev
$ git checkout dev
```

Более подробно можно ознакомиться вот тут: [Ветвление в Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 4):

разница в том, что:

1. с опцией `-b` команда `checkout` сначала попытается создать указанную ветку (`git branch ветка`), и, если ветка уже существует, вернёт ошибку:

   > fatal: A branch named 'ветка' already exists.
2. без опции `-b` предварительной попытки создать ветку не будет, потому, если такой ветки ещё не существует, будет возвращена ошибка:

   > error: pathspec 'ветка' did not match any file(s) known to git.

---

простое правило:

1. если ветка уже существует, для переключения на неё используйте

   ```
   $ git checkout ветка
   ```
2. если ветка **не** существует, для её создания и переключения на неё используйте:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b ветка
   ```